# Postmates API - Prevent duplicate delivery dispatches by passing reference

Tags: api, shopify, postmates

Currently working on an application for an eCommerce store that allows for Postmates deliveries of goods.  One case we encountered is the possibility for duplicate orders being created.  For example our application connects to Postmates creating a delivery but in hearing back from Postmates the connection drops never receiving confirmation. Our application assumes there was an error dispatching the delivery while in fact a delivery has been created.

Is there a way with Postmates API to let us pass a reference number so that Postmates will not allow the creation of two deliveries with the same reference number?

Answer (score 0):

yes, `manifest_reference` in the body of the payload when you request the delivery.

https://postmates.com/developer/docs/endpoints#create_delivery